# Activity starting again without any reason

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm starting an activity from my item inside my recycler view, but for some reason when my app enters a specific if statement inside a firebase database (**single value event**) listener. I don't know why this is happening and i'm trying 3 days now to solve this issue.

**I tried** removing this if statement and my app is working properly.

Here is my function with the firebase listener:

```
void sendNotificationToUser(String notificationType) {

    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    final String[] notification_message = {"none"};
    final String[] notification_title = {"none"};

    usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            String notificationID = usersRef.push().getKey();
            String currentDate = String.valueOf(android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy", new java.util.Date()));

            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int currentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int currentMinutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            if (notificationType.equals("profile_visit")) {

                notification_title[0] = "New profile visitor";
                notification_message[0] = user.getDisplayName() + " visited your profile";

                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (snap.child("name").getValue().toString().equals(username)) {
                        String postAuthorID = snap.child("id").getValue().toString();
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("title").setValue("New profile visitor");
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("type").setValue("profile_visit");
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("date").setValue(currentDate + "  " + currentHour + ":" + currentMinutes);
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("message").setValue(user.getDisplayName() + " visited your profile");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (notificationType.equals("follow")) {

                notification_title[0] = "New follower";
                notification_message[0] = user.getDisplayName() + " started following you";

                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (snap.child("name").getValue().toString().equals(username)) {
                        String postAuthorID = snap.child("id").getValue().toString();
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("title").setValue(notification_title[0]);
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("type").setValue("new_follower");
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("date").setValue(currentDate + "  " + currentHour + ":" + currentMinutes);
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("message").setValue(notification_message[0]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (notificationType.equals("screenshot")) {

                notification_title[0] = "Profile screenshot";
                notification_message[0] = user.getDisplayName() + " screenshotted your profile";

                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    if (snap.child("name").getValue().toString().equals(username)) {
                        String postAuthorID = snap.child("id").getValue().toString();
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("title").setValue(notification_title[0]);
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("type").setValue("profile_screenshot");
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("date").setValue(currentDate + "  " + currentHour + ":" + currentMinutes);
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("message").setValue(notification_message[0]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            else if (notificationType.equals("unfollow")) {

                notification_title[0] = "You lost a follower :(";
                notification_message[0] = user.getDisplayName() + " unfollowed you";

                for (DataSnapshot snap : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    if (snap.child("name").getValue().toString().equals(username)) {
                        String postAuthorID = snap.child("id").getValue().toString();
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("title").setValue(notification_title[0]);
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("type").setValue("unfollow");
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("date").setValue(currentDate + "  " + currentHour + ":" + currentMinutes);
                        usersRef.child(postAuthorID).child("notifications").child(notificationID).child("message").setValue(notification_message[0]);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // Find user token from DB
            // and add notification to Firestore
            for (DataSnapshot userSnap : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                if (userSnap.child("name").getValue(String.class).equals(username)) {

                    if (userSnap.child("fcm_token").exists()) {
                        // add notification to Firestore to send
                        // push notification from back-end
                        String firestoreNotificationID = usersRef.push().getKey();
                        Map<String, Object> notification = new HashMap<>();
                        notification.put("token", userSnap.child("fcm_token").getValue(String.class));
                        notification.put("title", notification_title[0]);
                        notification.put("message", notification_message[0]);
                        FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        firestore.collection("notifications")
                                .document(firestoreNotificationID).set(notification);
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(UserProfileActivity.this, "Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Can you share your code where you open a new activity. Perhaps your code above is indirect cause of your problem.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Please respond with @AlexMamo